# Is it possible to get the code behing azure table storage creation?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to get the code behind an azure table storage creation?For sql tables this is possible but for table storages i can't seem to find the code.Does anyone knows if the code is available somewhere?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/?toc=/azure/storage/tables/toc.json

Comment: already found and looked on that.What i need is something like this CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
   ....
); but this is for sql table, i need it for Table storage

Comment: There is no T-SQL support for Table Storage, and their is no specific query language built into Table Storage (aside from OData in the querystring, when making a GET call). At the lowest level, take a look at the REST API docs for Table Storage, which will show how to construct a POST for creating a table. Likewise, the various language-specific SDK's provide table-creation methods.

Comment: @SilviuAlexandru, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such `sql-like code` in behind.

When create an azure table storage, the [Create Table rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-table) is called by default. A screenshot as below:

[image]